# Run Selenium on Cloud Run using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a selenium based API on Google Cloud Run instead of AWS EC2. This is the code I tried to run on Cloud Run

```
import {Builder, Browser, By, Key, until} from "selenium-webdriver";
import fs from "fs";
import Axios from "axios";
import Queue from 'firebase-queue';
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import {Options} from "selenium-webdriver/chrome.js";
import {Firestore} from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import {Storage} from '@google-cloud/storage';
import express from 'express';

const firestore = new Firestore();
const storage = new Storage();


const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const options = new Options();

  options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
  options.addArguments('--headless')
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).setChromeOptions(options).build();
  driver.manage().window().setRect({ width: 3840, height: 2160, x: 0, y: 0 });

  await driver.get('https://google.com');
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  const pageSource = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('body')), timeoutMS).getAttribute('innerHTML');
  
  res.send(`Hello selenium!` + pageSource);
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I got an error

> The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from ...

Any idea on how to fix that? Is it even possible to run Selenium on Cloud Run?

Comment: It's a runtime execution. Share your Dockerfile and how you install (headless) Chrome on it. Then we will be able to help you

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share the code you're using to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is my hole code. I do not have a Dockerfile. So I understand I need I dockerfile to install Chrome?

Comment: Have you check out this two pages [Deploy a Node.js service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service) and [Deploy a containerised Node.js application to Cloud Run](https://medium.com/vinhle95/deploy-a-containerised-node-js-application-to-cloud-run-80d2da6b7040)